# Format date of Json from Laravel in Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a problem, I pass a date in d / m / Y format to Vue from Laravel and I want to increase it by one month, but when I try to do:

From laravel send it as a JSON collection:

```
'date' => date ('d/m/Y', strtotime ($row->date)),
```

03/08/2020

In Vue:

```
let nextdate = new Date(date);
```

I get the day and the month reversed.

Sun Mar 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Peru standard time)

It should come out, August 3, 2020.

Comment: Is it possible to send the date from Laravel to send a standard format? The [`Date(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor relies on [`Date.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) which considers mainly ISO format such as _2020-08-03_? Otherwise, you have to manually parse the API response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Carbon\Carbon::make($row->date)->setTimezone('America/Lima')->addMonth()->format('d/m/Y');
```

don't forget to double check your timezone `America/Lima` you can find your timezone [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)